# Design tab and Preview tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I get the design and preview tabs in android studio, right now i can only see xml text. all the previous SO question about this issue are outdated and the ide has changed its menus

Comment: try  Ctrl + Shift + RIGHT if you are using mac

Answer (score 1):

When viewing xml layouts you should have a design tab on your right, with it you can add a split window.

[image]

To fully move to the design view there's a tab on the bottom and it's been here for quite a while so I'm guessing its not what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: @Fuad well are you editing a layout xml? If not you won't see the options.

Comment: @Fuad open up a res/layout/* file and you'll have the options.

Answer (score 1):

When you're editing your layout file, there should be two tabs below the editor that say **Design** and **Text**. Click on Design. To open the Preview window, open your layout file and then go to View > Tool Windows > Preview.

Comment: no i dont have that option thats why im asking haha

Comment: Do you at least have the Preview option?

Comment: You..can't preview your Manifest file. Only your layout files.

Comment: I know, I just didnt realize